# How to use same instance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Question about C# Web API. How to achieve that working on same instance of class in attribute and action?

```
[CheckRole]
public HttpResponseMessage GetUser()
{
    if(new Engine().Method2()) throw new Exception();

    return ReturnSeccess200();
}


public class CheckRoleAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {
         if(new Engine().Method1()) throw new Exception();
    }
}


public class Engine
{
    public bool Method1(){ return true; }
    public bool Method2(){ return true; }
}
```

I want to have one instance on Engine class.

Comment: What about the [singleton pattern](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton)?

Comment: Leverage the singleton pattern or if you have a DI container, register the class as singleton

Comment: Create a global instance shared across all your web api calls.

Comment: or maybe just make the class static?

Answer (score 0):

If your methods doesn't use some property of instance `Engine`, you can make these methods as `static`

```
[CheckRole]
public HttpResponseMessage GetUser()
{
    if(Engine.Method2()) throw new Exception();

    return ReturnSeccess200();
}


public class CheckRoleAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {
         if(Engine.Method1()) throw new Exception();
    }
}


public class Engine
{
    public static bool Method1(){ return true; }
    public static  bool Method2(){ return true; }
}
```